# info emacs missing after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: emacs, info

After starting emacs 25 (GUI) and pressing C-h r I get the message "info emacs file missing". The same holds for the elisp manuals which are normally accessible from emacs. What happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing package `emacs25-common-non-dfsg` should solve the problem, as the package contain documentation for Emacs.

```
sudo apt install emacs25-common-non-dfsg
```

Comment: Apparently the package was there but not selected. Thnx.